# Is the restricted Boltzmann machine a type of graphical model (Bayesian network)?

Tags: neural-networks, graphical-model, restricted-boltzmann-machine

In general, neural networks are not graphical models due to the choice of the cost function,  but are restricted Boltzmann machines a special type of Bayesian networks?

Answer (score 9):

Boltzmann machines are graphical models, but they are *not* Bayesian networks.  They're a kind of Markov random field, which has *undirected* connections between the variables, while Bayesian networks have *directed* connections.

The difference between the two kinds of connections can be subtle, but the main advantage of undirected connections for an RBM is that inferring the hidden states associated with a set of visible states is much easier when the connections are undirected and there are many hidden variables.

Answer (score 1):

An RBM is an undirected graphical mode, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model) or [this paper](http://cui.unige.ch/~garg/publications/garg-acl2011.pdf).

Comment: But it's not a Bayesian network.  Bayesian networks are directed graphical models.